# Toggle class on input depending on input's value

Tags: angularjs

I am still new to Angular but I have an existing application that uses Angular 1.5 pretty heavily.

I have a basic form that I need to add a class to depending on the following criteria:

The form can only have an End Date value or an Active for value.  It cannot have both.  I was thinking I need to disable the input box of the input not being used.

Ex.  If a user inputs a date into the End Date input, then the Active for input will become disabled.

I looked into ng-if but every example I came across was for checking if the entered input variable was empty or equal to a value in a .js controller, not checking if the current entered variable was equal to another entered variable in the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>End date:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" is-open="endDateOpened" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="updatePatientLabel.active_end_date"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-search" ng-click="openEndDate($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Or will be active for:</label>
    <input name="expirationTimeNumber" type="number" class="form-control time" ng-model="updatePatientLabel.expiration_time_number"/>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of my modal where this happens.  Ignore the other inputs as they are not affected by the conditions I've laid out.

Thanks

[Form Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Datfa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-disabled`.

```
//initialize your dates with null
$scope.updatePatientLabel = {};
$scope.updatePatientLabel.active_end_date = null;
$scope.updatePatientLabel.expiration_time_number = null;
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="endDate" ng-disabled="updatePatientLabel.expiration_time_number !== null" ng-model="updatePatientLabel.active_end_date" />

<input id="activeDate" ng-disabled="updatePatientLabel.active_end_date !== null" ng-model="updatePatientLabel.expiration_time_number" />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. Classes, as you mentioned, or `ng-if`. The `ng-if` seems more elegant, like so:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-if="updatePatientLabel.active_end_date != ''">
    <label>End date:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" is-open="endDateOpened" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="updatePatientLabel.active_end_date"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-search" ng-click="openEndDate($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-if="updatePatientLabel.expiration_time_number > 0">
    <label>Or will be active for:</label>
    <input name="expirationTimeNumber" type="number" class="form-control time" ng-model="updatePatientLabel.expiration_time_number"/>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could do an inline conditional outputting "hidden" inside the `class` attribute only if the value is not present. Something like this:

```
<div class="form-group {{updatePatientLabel.active_end_date != '' ? '' : 'hidden'}}">
    <label>End date:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" is-open="endDateOpened" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="updatePatientLabel.active_end_date"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-search" ng-click="openEndDate($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group {{updatePatientLabel.expiration_time_number > 0 ? '' : 'hidden'}}">
    <label>Or will be active for:</label>
    <input name="expirationTimeNumber" type="number" class="form-control time" ng-model="updatePatientLabel.expiration_time_number"/>
</div>
```

I use both in my projects, and either way is perfectly acceptable. Though, `ng-if` does seem more elegant and a bit more suited for this scenario.